# Case Insensitive query in Datamapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I am new to Datamapper. Is there any way to write case insensitive query in datamapper because I am searching for presence of a name in a table with datamapper. Normally we write query in  datamapper like this say,

```
Student.all(:name => "XYZ") where name can be of the form xyz, Xyz and XYZ.
```

So in the above query what additional operator I have to add to make the above query case insensitive.

Comment: Check out this similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659045/case-insensitive-like-ilike-in-datamapper-with-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

For datamapper you have to use

```
Student.all(:conditions => [ "lower(name) = ?", name.downcase ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query:

```
name = "XyZ"
Student.find(:all, :conditions => [ "lower(name) = ?", name.downcase ])
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
name = "XyZ"
Student.where("lower(name) = ?", name.downcase)
```

or you can put validation in modal also like this

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false
```